# How i can refactor this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I have this method that i am using in if condition in my controller to continue execution.

```
def continue_bulk_action
 (@non_deleteable_invoices < 1 && params[:destroy] == "Delete") || (@unsendable_invoices == 0 && params[:send] == "Send") ||(params[:destroy] != "Delete" && params[:send] != "Send")
end
```

How i can refactor this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract the ***meaning*** out of each test. This makes the code more expressive.

```
def continue_bulk_action
  delete_with_no_deletable_invoices ||
  send_with_no_unsendable_invoices ||
  not_delete_or_send
end

def delete_with_no_deletable_invoices
  @non_deleteable_invoices < 1 && params[:destroy] == "Delete"
end

def send_with_no_unsendable_invoices
  @unsendable_invoices == 0 && params[:send] == "Send"
end

def not_delete_or_send
  params[:destroy] != "Delete" && params[:send] != "Send"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

IMO this is easier to read, it is also a bit more efficient:

```
def continue_bulk_action
  if params[:destroy] == "Delete"
    @non_deleteable_invoices < 1
  elsif params[:send] == "Send"
    @unsendable_invoices == 0
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to reuse `continue_bulk_action` method in 3 other methods. Why don't you move Destroy/Send conditions to methods where they will be used and don't keep then in one method?